# Why isn't my time uniform updating in my actual glsl code?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, glsl, react-three-fiber

I'm creating an editor for coding shaders in the browser, and I'd like to include a uniform that updates every frame so that I can do animations. I have an array of "Uniform" objects that I convert into a large uniform object that's then passed to the shaderMaterial of the object in my react-three-fiber scene (this is done so that I can render them for editing, etc. more easily through my react UI). All of my custom uniforms work fine, and I can see from console logs that my uTime time variable is indeed being updated each frame, but it doesn't appear to be affecting my output in the browser.

```js
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Uniform } from "../Editor/Uniforms/uniform.types";
import {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three'
type ShadedObjectProps = {
  fragmentShader: string;
  vertexShader: string;
  uniforms: Uniform[];
  children: any; // the geometry passed in; not sure how to actually type this
}

function buildUniforms(uniforms: Uniform[], elapsedTime: number) {
  const formattedUniforms: { [key: string]: any } = {
    uTime: {value: elapsedTime}
  };
  for (const uniform of uniforms) {
    formattedUniforms[uniform.name] = {value: new THREE[uniform.type](...uniform.value)};
  }
  return formattedUniforms;
}

export default function ShadedObject({fragmentShader, vertexShader, uniforms, children} : ShadedObjectProps ) {
  const materialRef = useRef<THREE.ShaderMaterial>(null); // ensure type correctness and non-undefined
  const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0)
  const shaderUniforms = buildUniforms(uniforms, elapsedTime);

  // update the time uniform
  useFrame((state) => {
    setElapsedTime(state.clock.elapsedTime);
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (materialRef.current) {
      // If the material already exists, update the shaders
      materialRef.current.fragmentShader = fragmentShader;
      materialRef.current.vertexShader = vertexShader;
      materialRef.current.uniforms = shaderUniforms;
      materialRef.current.needsUpdate = true; // Trigger material update
    }
  }, [fragmentShader, vertexShader, shaderUniforms]);
  console.log(materialRef.current?.uniforms)
  return (
    <group>
      <mesh>
        {children} 
        <shaderMaterial
          ref={materialRef}
          fragmentShader={fragmentShader}
          vertexShader={vertexShader}
          uniforms={shaderUniforms}
        />
      </mesh>
    </group>
  )
}


// type definition that's usually in another file
import * as THREE from 'three';
type UniformKey = 'Vector2' | 'Vector3';

export type Uniform = {
  [K in UniformKey]: {
    name: string;
    type: K;
    value: ConstructorParameters<typeof THREE[K]>;
  }
}[UniformKey]
```

The console logs confirm that my uniform object, once built, is indeed being updated, but this doesn't show up in my actual threejs scene when I modify the glsl code.